# Display an image with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to use Tkinter to display an image in Python 2.7. Below is an example of a code I tried to use, which displays all images in the folder (from
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/521918-pil-and-tkinter-to-display-images/ ):

```
import os, sys
import Tkinter
import Image, ImageTk

def button_click_exit_mainloop (event):
    event.widget.quit() # this will cause mainloop to unblock.

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.bind("<Button>", button_click_exit_mainloop)
root.geometry('+%d+%d' % (100,100))
dirlist = os.listdir('.')
old_label_image = None
for f in dirlist:
    try:
        image1 = Image.open(f)
        root.geometry('%dx%d' % (image1.size[0],image1.size[1]))
        tkpi = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
        label_image = Tkinter.Label(root, image=tkpi)
        label_image.place(x=0,y=0,width=image1.size[0],height=image1.size[1])
        root.title(f)
        if old_label_image is not None:
            old_label_image.destroy()
        old_label_image = label_image
        root.mainloop() # wait until user clicks the window
    except Exception, e:
        # This is used to skip anything not an image.
        # Image.open will generate an exception if it cannot open a file.
        # Warning, this will hide other errors as well.
        pass
```

For instance, a cross (top) will lead to the following displayed image in the Tkinter window (bottom):[image]

I have tried other codes (including some to display live my webcam), they all lead to the same result: I can see an image, it has the correct dimension, but each column has a constant pixel value (the one of the corresponding column of the first row of the original image).